# Syntax highlighting, with case insensitive syntax

Tags: php, str-replace, case-sensitive

I am trying to write a search and syntax highlighter. Let's presume we have a basic query, that is querying for countries based on a keyword, for example **uni**.

Right now, I am using Sphinx, to fetch the results that match with this keyword from a database, and I am using case-insensitive search. The results that sphinx return are the following:

```
Tanzania, United Republic of
United Arab Emirates
United Kingdom
United States
Igaunija
Estados unidos Mexicanos
```

I now want to highlight the search keyword from these strings, by wrapping the keyword in a `<span>`.

To achieve this, I was trying to do the following:

```
$search='uni';
foreach($keyword as $text) { // $keyword is an array, containg each found result one by one
  $text=str_replace($search, "<span>".$search."</span>", $text);
}
```

Whit this code, only `Iguanija`, and `Estados unidos Mexicanos` gets highlighted, because in every other case the keyword starts with an uppercase letter. If I change the `str_replace` to a `str_ireplace`, every search keyword get's highlighted, but in the first few entries, the uppercase `U` gets replaced with a lowercase `u`, so from `United Kingdom`, I get `united Kingdom`. How could I highlight the search keyword, and maintain the case of the characters in the result?

My desired result would be something like this:

```
Tanzania, <span>Uni</span>ted Republic of
<span>Uni</span>ted Arab Emirates
<span>Uni</span>ted Kingdom
<span>Uni</span>ted States
Iga<span>uni</span>ja
Estados <span>uni</span>dos Mexicanos
```

Comment: What's the content of `$search`? What's the content of `$keyword`? Why are you copying `$keyword` into `$text`?

Comment: $search is **uni**, and $keyword is each word in order from the list of found words.

Comment: Use `preg_replace()`. Then you can use `$0` in the replacement to get the text from the original, so it will keep the case.

Comment: user2182349 beat me to it, but you might want to explode the string and mark the entire word instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression which will allow you to preserve the case of the source string.

```
<?php

$unis = <<< UNIS
Tanzania, United Republic of
United Arab Emirates
United Kingdom
United States
Igaunija
Estados unidos Mexicanos
UNIS;

var_dump(preg_replace('/(uni)/i','<span>$1</span>',$unis));
```

**Output**

```
string(190) "Tanzania, <span>Uni</span>ted Republic of
<span>Uni</span>ted Arab Emirates <span>Uni</span>ted Kingdom
<span>Uni</span>ted States Iga<span>uni</span>ja Estados
<span>uni</span>dos Mexicanos"
```